# Batches are aborted using Datacap WTM Service by Java Application

Tags: java, ibm-data-studio, ibm-datacap

We are creating batches using WTM Service in java.

Steps :

1. Login to Datacap using Session/Logon - 200 status
2. Create Batch using Queue/CreateBatch - 200 status
3. Upload File using Queue/UploadFile/Application/QueueID - 200 status
4. Release Batch Queue/ReleaseBatch/Application/QueueID/finished- 200 status

Batches are created in Datacap. But aborted.

No logs are generating in batch folder.

scan.xml file is generating and that file contains encoded binary data along with below content :

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tm000002.tif"; filename="tm000002.tif" Content-Type: application/tiff Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Please help us to generate logs and resolve issue.

Comment: Please help somebody...

Comment: Please suggest me why scan.xml file is overriding by (binary data) the file that we uploaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Steps reported are correct and complete.
Troubleshoot issue based on exception observed in **wTM** log, **TMS** log.